# Printing contents of a tsv file (with UTF-8) in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, utf-8, kivy

The code I have below works fine in a file I've named tsv_test.py:

```
import csv

class ReadUTF8():

    def unicode_csv_reader(self, utf8_data, dialect=csv.excel_tab, **kwargs):
        csv_reader = csv.reader(utf8_data, dialect=dialect, **kwargs)
        for row in csv_reader:
            yield [unicode(cell, 'utf-8') for cell in row]


    def load_deck_data(self):
        filename = 'lexicon.tsv'
        reader = self.unicode_csv_reader(open(filename))
        for field1, field2, field3, field4 in reader:
            print field1, field2, field3, field4

ReadUTF8().load_deck_data()
```

But when I copy/paste it into my project (this is a kivy project), it breaks.  Code and error below:

```
class StudyScreenManagement(ScreenManager):

    def unicode_csv_reader(self, utf8_data, dialect=csv.excel_tab, **kwargs):
        csv_reader = csv.reader(utf8_data, dialect=dialect, **kwargs)
        for row in csv_reader:
            yield [unicode(cell, 'utf-8') for cell in row]


    def load_deck_data(self):
        filename = 'lexicon.tsv'
        reader = self.unicode_csv_reader(open(filename))
        for field1, field2, field3, field4 in reader:
            print field1, field2, field3, field4
```

I doubt this is related, but just in case, the related .kv file:

```
Button:
    text: 'Lexicon'
    on_press: app.root.load_deck_data()
```

Output:

```
 File "/Users/bearnun/code/mingyu/mingyuKivy/mingyu_controllers.py", line 14, in load_deck_data
 for field1, field2, field3, field4 in reader:
 ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

::Side Note::

I tried just printing 'field1' in both cases.  With that change the output for both is:

```
[u'\u4b03', u'\u98d2', u'[sa4]', u'/variant of \u98af|\u98d2[sa4]/']
[u'\u4b20', u'\u4b20', u'[fei1]', u'/old variant of \u970f[fei1]/']
```

My desired output:

```
䬃 飒 [sa4] /variant of 颯|飒[sa4]/
䬠 䬠 [fei1] /old variant of 霏[fei1]/
```

[EDIT BELOW]

lexicon.tsv contents:

```
䬃   飒   [sa4]   /variant of 颯|飒[sa4]/
䬠   䬠   [fei1]  /old variant of 霏[fei1]/
```

Comment: Something is giving you a `row` with one field, instead of 4. Are you sure both the csv and the tsv files have the same content?

Comment: Yes, sorry that was a typo.  Everything that I have been working on is in tsv format.

Comment: You need to post your tsv file, e.g. three lines of the file that when run with your program will reproduce the error.

Comment: @7stud .tsv added -- Going through your response now. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Apparently, I am receiving a list instead of a generator, so if in
>   load_deck_data() I change:
>
> ```
> for field1, field2, field3, field4 in reader:
>     print field1, field2, field3, field4
> ```
>
> to:
>
> ```
> for line in reader:
>     print ''.join(line)
> ```
>
> my project works fine.

Check out this example:

```
data = [
    ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
    ['e'],
]

def mygen(x):
    for item in x:
        yield item

for line in mygen(data):
    print ''.join(line)

--output:--
abcd
e

for col1, col2, col3, col4 in mygen(data):
    print col1, col2, col3, col4


--output:--
a b c d

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "1.py", line 13, in <module>
    for col1, col2, col3, col4 in mygen(data):
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

In the first for-in loop, you are asking, "Please retrieve all the elements in the list and join them together."  In the second for-in loop, you are demanding, "Retrieve four elements from the list!"  See the difference?  In the first case, the list can contain 0 to n elements and there won't be an error.  In the second case, the list has to have at least 4 elements--otherwise there will be an error.

> I would love to know why I'm getting a generator in one place, but a list in another.

Simple.  You aren't. `csv.reader()` returns a list of strings for each row, which means `your generator function` returns a list of strings for each iteration.

I think you changed the data in your file. In one file, you have `tab delimited` data, and `csv.reader()` returns a list of four things for each line in your file, which can be unpacked into four variables; but your other file has `non-tab delimited` data, which causes `csv.reader()` to read the whole line as one item, so the list of strings that csv.reader() returns contains only one item, and a one item list cannot be unpacked into four variables.

> I tried just printing 'field1' in both cases. With that change the
>   output for both is:
>
> ```
> [u'\u4b03', u'\u98d2', u'[sa4]', u'/variant of \u98af|\u98d2[sa4]/']
> [u'\u4b20', u'\u4b20', u'[fei1]', u'/old variant of \u970f[fei1]/']
> ```

Instead of doing `print field1`, if you do `print repr(field1)` I suspect you will get:

```
"[u'\u4b03', u'\u98d2', u'[sa4]', u'/variant of \u98af|\u98d2[sa4]/']"
```

Note the outer quotes, which means your tsv file literally has the following on one line:

```
[䬃, 飒, [sa4], /variant of 颯|飒[sa4]/]
```

with no tabs separating anything, so the whole line-that-looks-like-a-list is read in as one item, therefore csv.reader() returns a list containing that one item.  You were fooled into thinking the single item was a python list because when you print a string, python does not display the quotes. For example, there is no difference in the output for the following two print statements:

```
>>> print "[1, 2, 3]"
[1, 2, 3]
>>> print [1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
```

`print` can fool you in other situations as well because a string can contain unprintable characters, which the output of print won't reveal:

```
>>> print "hello\bworld"
hellworld
```

The bottom line is: you can never know what the original thing was by looking at the output of print.  Whenever you want to know exactly what the original thing is, always use:

```
print repr(some_string)
```

Now, look at the results:

```
>>> print repr([1, 2, 3])
[1, 2, 3]
>>> print repr('[1, 2, 3]')
'[1, 2, 3]'
>>> print repr('hello\bworld')
'hello\x08world'
```

The output tells you exactly what the original thing was.

With the following tab delimited `lexicon.tsv` file:

```
1   2   3   €
䬃   飒   [sa4]   /variant of 颯|飒[sa4]/
```

the code below causes no errors after clicking on the Lexicon button:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
import csv

class StudyScreenManager(ScreenManager):

    def unicode_csv_reader(self, utf8_data, dialect=csv.excel_tab, **kwargs):
        csv_reader = csv.reader(utf8_data, dialect=dialect, **kwargs)
        for row in csv_reader:
            yield [unicode(cell, 'utf-8') for cell in row]


    def load_deck_data(self):
        filename = 'lexicon.tsv'
        reader = self.unicode_csv_reader(open(filename))
        for field1, field2, field3, field4 in reader:
            print field1, field2, field3, field4


class HistoryScreen(Screen):
    pass

class MathScreen(Screen):
    pass

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        sm = StudyScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(HistoryScreen(name='history'))
        sm.add_widget(MathScreen(name='math'))

        return sm

MyApp().run()
```

my.kv:

```
<HistoryScreen>:  #the 'root' of the following widget hierarchy:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: 'Lexicon'
            on_press: app.root.load_deck_data()  #self=Button, root=HistoryScreen, app.root=the Widget returned by build()
        Button:
            text: "Next"
            on_press: root.manager.current = "math"

<MathScreen>: #the 'root' of the following widget heirarchy:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: 'Lexicon'
            on_press: app.root.load_deck_data()
        Button:
            text: 'Previous'
            on_press: root.manager.current = "history"
```

After clicking on the Lexicon button, here is the output I see in my `utf-8 aware terminal window`:

```
1 2 3 €
䬃 飒 [sa4] /variant of 颯|飒[sa4]/
```

Comment: Wow!  This is a wonderful response -- thanks so much!  And yes, it seems like my .tsv file was in bad shape...When I used an automatically generated .tsv file, everything works fine.  

And I had no idea repr() existed.  That's useful to know --thanks!! :D

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I am receiving a list instead of a generator, so if in load_deck_data() I change...:

```
for field1, field2, field3, field4 in reader:
    print field1, field2, field3, field4
```

...to...:

```
for line in reader:
    print ''.join(line)
```

...my project works fine.  This, of course, does not work in the small code snippet that originally worked.

I would love to know why I'm getting a generator in one place, but a list in another.  :)

Comment: I don't think that's the problem. All a tuple of 4 elements, a list of 4 elements or a generator that yields 4 values can be unpacked to 4 variables. What about `print len(line)` or `print type(line)`? Or `print repr(line)`?